# 20 hours layover Dubai

Tags: budget, planning, layovers, dubai, dxb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A day at Dubai International Airport and the city?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5605/a-day-at-dubai-international-airport-and-the-city)

I will be in Dubai for a 20 hours layover in the middle of November. It will be a Tuesday (13th).

I know that I will have (as Italian) a free visa for visiting the city and that the downtown is only 20 minutes form the airport (by taxi or metro, right?).

What would be a good program for that layover?
How much should I expect to spend?

Comment: What are you planning to do there? That'll make a big difference to the cost... If it's just ride the metro about to see different things, that's very different to getting taxis between lots of shopping malls and entertainment activities

Comment: @Gagravarr mmm, I would like to use the metro as much as possible. I would like to see the main attractions e the biggest mall. Thans

Comment: @PeterHahndorf It could be, I didn't noticed it. However I'm asking for a detailed program with attractions and transportation costs.

Comment: You really do need to provide some more detail.  There's SO much to do in Dubai - it's a big city!  What are you interested in? Museums? Shopping? Skiing?

Comment: @MarkMayo Thanks Mark. I would avoid Skiing, probably Alps are better :-) I would like to see some souks, some heritage areas, the biggest mall and of course the fountains.