# Is there anything to do during an 8 hour after-midnight layover in Dubai?

Tags: layovers, dubai, nightlife, night-transport

We are planning a trip with an 8 hour layover in Dubai spanning from 1am-9am. I am thinking about going to see the city, but is it worth it to do it given the very late night hours? Will at least the outside attractions accessible?

Will Burj Khalifa be visible in the middle of the night?

Will at least some of the malls be open?

Will there be anything to do at night?

I have seen other questions about layovers in Dubai ([A day at Dubai International Airport and the city?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5605/a-day-at-dubai-international-airport-and-the-city)), but none of them is asking about a night-only stay.

Comment: There's zero to do.  However dbx has the most awesome in-airport hotel, so if possible stay there to relax!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

General answer... There's not so much to do at very night hours in Dubai apart from Disco or other bars/lounges, and for sure not in the very late hours of the night...

To answer your specific questions:

- Burj Khalifa is open from 8.30 am to 1.00 am, but last entrance is 45 mins. before so it will be closed.
- Dubai Mall [is not open](http://www.thedubaimall.com/en/Information/OpeningHours.aspx), neither the [Mall of Emirates](http://www.malloftheemirates.com/general-pages/opening-hours.aspx).
- I think there's nothing much to do than staying at the airport. I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question. We decided to add 24 hours to the stopover and spend a full day in Dubai.

Answer (score 11):

Most things are indeed closed, but there are some things that are open 24h and worthwhile, although knowing the season you're visiting would be helpful.

Top of my list would be relaxing with a Arabic meal and a puff or ten of ''shisha'' (water pipe) at a [good 24h restaurant](http://www.timeoutdubai.com/gallery/34522-24-hour-dining-in-dubai).  I have a soft spot for [Kan Zaman](http://alkoufa.com/en/restaurants/kan-zaman), which has good food, good shisha, tolerable prices and a great creekside location in the Heritage Village.

The Burj Khalifa's viewing deck closes at 1 AM.  However, you can tour the outside of the building and watch the fountains.

Malls usually close at 10 PM, although if you happen to visit during Ramadan, most all stretch their opening hours late into the night.  The main exception is actually Dubai Airport itself, which is open 24h and has a ridiculously huge shopping area offering pretty much anything -- it's more like a Costco than your average duty-free.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the tips what to do at night in Dubai

Comment: The fountains will be finished for the night before he gets there, unfortunately.