# What to do with 7 hours transit in Dubai from midnight?

Tags: dubai

I am planning a trip with a 7-hour layover in Dubai, from 1am to 8am. I am thinking about going to see the city and I would appreciate if you could advise me to some places (which are beautiful at night). Also, what are the prices of taxis over there? Is there any way to pay a taxi for a 6-7 hours tours (fixed price) and if it is how much would it cost?

Thank you in advance. I have been searching for answers already but none of them are completely answered or are possibly outdated (7 years +).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there anything to do during an 8 hour after-midnight layover in Dubai?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24630/is-there-anything-to-do-during-an-8-hour-after-midnight-layover-in-dubai)